# Enter formula as string in a (named) Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following question.
Let's say there are two named Tables (as in HOME/Format as Table):

OPS:

```
operation   formula
sum         =[@Col2] + [@Col3]
diff        =[@Col2] - [@Col3]
```

MYTABLE:

```
operation   Col2    Col3    result
sum         1       2   
diff        1       2
```

It is possible to put a formula in the `result` column in `MYTABLE` by looking it up from `OPS` based on the contents of column `MYTABLE[operation]`?

The lookup is easy but returns the contents of `OPS[formula]` as text and I have not been able to convert it to a formula that calculates.

`=INDEX(OPS[formula], MATCH([@operation], OPS[operation], 0), 1)`

I did find some solutions using `VBA Evaluate()` but it does not seem to work in Tables (the result is always a #VALUE! error).

Comment: There are limitations to this approach.  [This SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471884/how-to-turn-a-string-formula-into-a-real-formula) outlines several things you could try.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid this was going to be the answer, as I did read through the linked SO question before posting, but was hoping someone had a different approach.